# Can a write to remote DB operation be in a separate aynchronous thread? (Delphi)

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, rest, delphi

Delphi XE8. A mobile application running on iOS and Android will be storing data to a local SQLLite DB. A background thread would then transfer the data from local DB to a remote enterprise database using REST. I was wondering if this operation of sending data to a remote database server using REST can asynchronously execute in a thread of its own, or would that thread need to be Synchronized with the main UI thread? The background data transfer thread will have no interactions with, or dependency on, the main UI. It will only read committed records from the local DB (which would have been written by the main UI thread) and make REST operations to write to a remote database.

Comment: You can use a **Service** and start a **Thread** inside the Service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: This is where you need to implement layers. `Communication > Business Logic > User Interface`, for example. The thread could feed a queue of messages or commands to the UI, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example, how to create a separate service, then use it to do what you need, using a thread.

[Delphi and Android services](http://blog.blong.com/2015/02/delphi-and-android-services-part-3.html)

Here the source code for delphi XE7
[Delphi Xe7 source code](http://blong.com/Downloads/DelphiServiceDemo.7z)